# Citer correctement les passages coraniques

Tags: typographie, abréviations, religion, citations

Je me demandais si, dans l’édition francophone, une nomenclature était établie pour citer correctement, et selon les normes établies en typographie française, un passage du Coran, aussi bien une [*sourate*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sourate)  qu’une [*āya*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aya_(islam)).

Je pose la question car des traductions de référence de la Bible comme la TOB mirent au point un système d’abréviations et d’identification (que je décris [ici](http://taniere.info/littera/idiolecte/abbr/#Bible-citation)) très efficace.

Par ailleurs, j’ai trouvé dans mon édition traduite du Coran (*Initiation à l’interprétation objective du texte intraductible du Saint Coran* par le D<sup>r</sup> Salah ed-Dine Kechrid) un système de référence qui utilisait le numéro de la sourate plutôt qu’une abréviation du nom traduit… ce qui ne me séduit guère.

Bref, y a-t-il dans l’édition francophone des traductions du Coran un système de référencement ayant recourt aux abréviations ?

Comment: Il semble qu'il n'y a pas que le français qui aie choisi de numéroter les sourates. C'est également l'usage en anglais si j'en crois https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_suras_in_the_Quran.

Answer (score 2):

Les abréviations citées font références aux livres (de 66 à 81 livres, selon les confessions catholique romaine, protestante, orthodoxe, ...) qui composent la Bible chrétienne.

À l'intérieur de ceux-là les chapitres sont numérotés, et les versets le sont aussi au second niveau d'indexation.

Le Coran n'est fait que d'un seul livre, selon les paroles d'un seul prophète.

Il a hérité du référencement et des usages typographiques liés aux livres saints antérieurs.

Comment: Donc, si j’ai bien compris le *Coran* est vu comme un livre unitaire, comparable editoriallement au livre de la *Genèse* par exemple. Or, comme l’on ne fait pas d’abréviation pour la composition interne d’un livre mais seulement une numérotation des chapitres et versets, l’usage de numéroter les sourates (homologues des chapitres) n’est que parfaitement analogue à celui des livres saints du christianisme.
Y suis-je ?

Comment: @Fauve - C'est comme cela que j'analyse la typographie adoptée dans les versions francophones - **Il serait intéressant de savoir si d'autres langues adoptent les références arabophones.**